# Solving a difference of powers equation

Tags: number-theory

Is there a general method for solving this equation:

$p^q - q^p = N$

Here $N$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $e < p < q$ integers,  we get
$$ p^q - q^p \geq p^{p+1} - (p+1)^p \approx (p-e) \; p^p  $$
Having written it out,
$$  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2p} \right) e <  \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p} \right)^p < e, $$ so
$$ p^q - q^p \geq p^{p+1} - (p+1)^p > (p-e) \; p^p  $$
Not so much a method as a proof of finiteness with explicit bound, meaning one may quickly check. Finally,
$$ 2^q - q^2  $$ is also pretty big.